# Finding a Dual Basis $B^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$ and let $S^*=\{x_1, x_2\}$ be it's dual basis.  Let $B=\{(1, 2),(4,7)\}$ be another basis of $\Bbb R^2$.  Compute $B^*$ in terms of $x_1, x_2$

I don't particularly understand.  I know for example that for $f_i(b_j)=1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.  But farther than that I don't really get it.

I think I have to find $2$ vectors for $B^*$, that follow $f_1(b^*_1)=1$, and so on following the above form.  I get lost going beyond this idea of what a dual basis is though

Any help, tips or resources to go look at is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following the definition that you've given, you should be able to verify that the functions $x_i$ on vectors $(v_1,v_2)$ are defined by
$$
x_1(v_1,v_2) = v_1\\
x_2(v_1,v_2) = v_2
$$
Similarly, if $y_i$ are the elements of $B^*$, we have
$$
y_1(v_1,v_2) = a_1 v_1 + b_1 v_2\\
y_2(v_1,v_2) = a_2 v_1 + b_2 v_2
$$
where $a_i,b_i$ are chosen so that the $y_i$ satisfy the definition of the dual basis.

For $y_1$, we have
$$
y_1(1,2) = a_1 + 2b_1 = 1\\
y_1(4,7) = 4a_1 + 7b_1 = 0
$$
Solve this system to find that $a_1 = -7, b_1 = 4$.  In particular, this means that
$$
y_1(v_1,v_2) = -7x_1(v_1,v_2) + 4x_2(v_1,v_2)
$$
That is, $y_1 = -7x_1 + 4x_2$ is *an expression for $y_1$ in terms of $x_1,x_2$*.  Do the same for $y_2$, and you will have completely answered the question.

Comment: Would I then write $B^*=((-7x_1,4x_2), (2x_1,-x_2))$?  Great answer by the way, I understand what I'm doing now thanks!

Comment: That notation isn't quite correct; I would write
$$
B^* = (-7x_1 + 4x_2, 2x_1 - x_2)
$$
I suppose that you could write something like
$$
-7x_1 + 4x_2 = (-7,4)
$$
where $(-7,4)$ is a coordinate vector with respect to the dual basis.

Comment: Oh yes that makes more sense, it even matches up with $S^*$ in the question.  The two functionals are the values.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First calculates the dual basis of $B$ and then put it as a linear combination of $(x_{1},x_{2})$

Answer (score 1):

You need to find $f_i$ such that $f_i(b_j) = \delta_{ij}$.
I use $e_1^*, e_2^*$ to denote the standard dual basis.

You will have $f_1 = a e_1^* + be_2^*$, $f_2 = c e_1^* + de_2^*$.

Then $f_i(b_j) = \delta_{ij}$ will give four equations in $a,b,c,d$. Solve
them.

Note that this is the same as solving
$\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} \pmatrix{1 & 4 \\ 2 & 7} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 }$.

Solution:

> You will get $f_1 = -7 e_1^* + 4 e_2^*$, $f_2 = 2 e_1^* -e_2^*$.